# Flot Disable panRange

Tags: flot

How can I set Flot panRange so that I can only pan in x-axis and not y-axis?
I tried setting panRange in the y-axis to the following but neither worked:

panRange: null
panRange: none

I am using mouse's scroll wheel to zoom in and out.

Thanks

Comment: as a quick fix. I set the y-axis panRange(0, MAX_Y) and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the panRange to 'false' on the axis that you want to remain fixed.